# Display stacked lines charts in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, syncfusion

How can I display stacked lines like this photo? I'm using Syncfusion flutter package
[image: Chart]

I can display one line but when using stacked it's not mixed like this? it's just two lines that never cross each other and they also look weird like this
[image: this is what I get]

Comment: share ur code too

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, it is not possible to achieve it using the StackedLineSeries type because it is designed to stack multiple line series on top of each other, and one stacked series does not overlap with other stacked series. However, you can achieve your requirement using the LineSeries type. The LineSeries allows you to plot individual line series without stacking them. We have shared the related UG documentation below.

UG, https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/chart-types/line-chart